# How you use virtualenv within python script, so we need not to activate it everytime

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, shebang

Currently I'm running this command in terminal:

```
source /home/protected/env/bin/activate
```

And then I run this and it works:

```
python3 /home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py
```

But it seems like it should be required to enter `source /home/protected/env/bin/activate` first.  Is it not possible to specify the path somewhere within the python script or at least a way to turn this into a one-liner instead of having to send 2 separate commands?

Comment: A 2-line batch file or shell script could do this, and you could call the batch file/script with a one-line command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can just change the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to this

```
#!/home/protected/env/bin/python
```

Then you invoke the script like so (this is your one-liner)

```
/home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py
```

Note that it needs to be executable, you can change it like this

```
chmod u+x /home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py
```

If you invoke the python interpreter inside the Virtual Environment, it will act as if the activate script was first sourced. Note that you don't even need to specify "python3", but can just go "python"

Comment: Tried that and got this error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sha3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sha3'```

Comment: How do you invoke the script?

Comment: I'm just running ```python3 /home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py```

Comment: I see where you said to just run ```/home/protected/ethereum-wallet-generator.py``` instead of what I was doing.  Thanks it works!